# axios or fetch giving network error to any HTTP call

Tags: react-native

I am having issues making a simple call to my development or even production app. The environment is :

```
"axios": "^0.19.0",
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-native": "0.60.5"
```

API is built with:

```
 Django 1.11 and DRF
```

the AVDs I tried are Android 9 API 28, Android 8 API 27.

My development machine runs on http://localhost:9000 and even https://localhost:9000 (with runsslserver) and the same app that is on production is https://example.net/api/

With axios, I call it like this:

```
axios
  .post(APIS.START.LOGIN, {loginData})
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    console.log(res.data);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  })
  .finally(console.log('done'));
```

The error I am getting with fetch and axios are similar: network failure. Console log of axios is:

```
done
D:\dev\go\mobile_apps\agronomo\screens\guest\ScreenLogin.js:69 Error: Network Error
    at createError (D:\dev\go\mobile_apps\agronomo\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (D:\dev\go\mobile_apps\agronomo\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:81)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (D:\dev\go\mobile_apps\agronomo\node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:818)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (D:\dev\go\mobile_apps\agronomo\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:574)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (D:\dev\go\mobile_apps\agronomo\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:388)
    at D:\dev\go\mobile_apps\agronomo\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:501
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (D:\dev\go\mobile_apps\agronomo\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:189)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (D:\dev\go\mobile_apps\agronomo\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:395)
    at D:\dev\go\mobile_apps\agronomo\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:106
    at MessageQueue.__guard (D:\dev\go\mobile_apps\agronomo\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:343)
D:\dev\go\mobile_apps\agronomo\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\YellowBox\YellowBox.js:71 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
TypeError: f is not a function
TypeError: f is not a function
    at blob:file:///bdfd99d2-9789-4422-9c3b-ab0962405db9:42178:30
    at tryCallOne (blob:file:///bdfd99d2-9789-4422-9c3b-ab0962405db9:45399:14)
    at blob:file:///bdfd99d2-9789-4422-9c3b-ab0962405db9:45500:17
    at blob:file:///bdfd99d2-9789-4422-9c3b-ab0962405db9:45801:21
    at _callTimer (blob:file:///bdfd99d2-9789-4422-9c3b-ab0962405db9:45690:9)
    at _callImmediatesPass (blob:file:///bdfd99d2-9789-4422-9c3b-ab0962405db9:45726:9)
    at Object.callImmediates (blob:file:///bdfd99d2-9789-4422-9c3b-ab0962405db9:45945:14)
    at MessageQueue.__callImmediates (blob:file:///bdfd99d2-9789-4422-9c3b-ab0962405db9:15222:16)
    at blob:file:///bdfd99d2-9789-4422-9c3b-ab0962405db9:15028:18
    at MessageQueue.__guard (blob:file:///bdfd99d2-9789-4422-9c3b-ab0962405db9:15205:13)
console.warn @ D:\dev\go\mobile_apps\agronomo\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\YellowBox\YellowBox.js:71
onUnhandled @ D:\dev\go\mobile_apps\agronomo\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Promise.js:37
onUnhandled @ D:\dev\go\mobile_apps\agronomo\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\rejection-tracking.js:71
(anonymous) @ D:\dev\go\mobile_apps\agronomo\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:250
_callTimer @ D:\dev\go\mobile_apps\agronomo\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:146
callTimers @ D:\dev\go\mobile_apps\agronomo\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:399
__callFunction @ D:\dev\go\mobile_apps\agronomo\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:395
(anonymous) @ D:\dev\go\mobile_apps\agronomo\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:106
__guard @ D:\dev\go\mobile_apps\agronomo\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:343
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue @ D:\dev\go\mobile_apps\agronomo\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:105
e @ RNDebuggerWorker.js:1
```

Comment: It works on production but not in your machine?
Have you checked if the SSL encryption is the issue?

Comment: hey @AndréPinto it doesn't work on production or the localhost. The production one has a proper SSL certificate while the dev one is a self-signed certificate.